# How to grep a program's output but also echo the output normally?

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, io-redirection

I'm working with a program that outputs error messages when something goes wrong, but does not set its exit status accordingly:  the exit status is always 0, indicating success.  I'd like to run this program from a shell script and get a non-zero exit status if it emits any error messages, so the script can tell that the program failed.

The error messages follow a predictable pattern that I can match with `grep`, and `grep` sets its exit status based on whether it found a match, so I can pipe the program's output into `grep` and negate the result with `!` to get the exit status I want.

The problem is that if I pipe into `grep`, I can't *see* the program's output anymore, because `grep` consumes it.  I'd like to somehow scan the output for error messages but also display the output normally, since there are other important messages besides the errors.  Unfortunately, `grep` doesn't have an option to pass-through all of its input, matching and non-matching lines alike.

One approach I've found that *mostly* works is:

```
! my_program | tee /dev/stderr | grep -q "error message"
```

This feeds the program's output into `grep` but also copies it to standard error, which isn't redirected, so I can see it.  That's OK when my script's standard output and standard error both go to a terminal (so it doesn't matter which one gets the messages), but it can cause problems if standard out and standard error are redirected to different places; the messages will end up in the wrong place.

Using `bash` or POSIX shell, and GNU tools, is there a (concise) way to scan a program's standard out and/or standard error streams with something like `grep` and set exit status accordingly, but also let both streams go to their normal destinations?

(Note that `my_program` writes its error messages to standard out, not standard error, so a solution that can only scan the standard output stream is OK, though not ideal.  And in case it makes a difference, I'm doing this on CentOS 7.)

Answer (score 7):

> ...is there a (concise) way to scan a program's standard out and/or standard error streams with something like grep and set exit status accordingly, but also let both streams go to their normal destinations?
>
> ...my_program writes its error messages to standard out, not standard error, so **a solution that can only scan the standard output stream is OK,** though not ideal.

My solution answers the **bolded** portion above.

I think the easiest way to do this is through `awk`:

```
myprogram |
awk 'BEGIN {status = 0} /error message/ {status = 1} 1; END {exit(status)}'
```

The `awk` command outputs everything it inputs exactly as-is, but at the end it exits with a status dependent on whether "error message" was a part of the input.

Concise version (with a shorter variable name):

```
myprogram | awk 'BEGIN{s=0} /error message/{s=1} 1; END{exit(s)}'
```

Comment: Also note, I am fairly certain it is fundamentally impossible to simultaneously scan `stdout` and `stderr`, *and* send them subsequently to two separate places.  Not to mention the fact that `stderr` is unbuffered and `stdout` is often buffered.

Comment: Correction to earlier comment: It *is* possible, but not with standard utilities.  So, not *fundamentally* impossible.  (To do so, you could use `mkfifo` to set up the stdout and stderr targets, then open them for reading using a custom-written program which will read from both sources and write each to the appropriate file descriptor, like a dual-action `cat`, and check for a pattern in each along the way.)

Answer (score 6):

Here are some one liners that grep the error message `$MSG` on stdout/stderr, and do/do not stop the program as soon as the error message appears:

```
# grep on stdout, do not stop early
my_program | awk -v s="$MSG" '$0~s{r=1} 1; END{exit(r)}'

# grep on stdout, do stop early
my_program | awk -v s="$MSG" '$0~s{exit(1)} 1'

# grep on stderr, do not stop early
{ my_program 2>&1 >&3 | awk -v s="$MSG" '$0~s{r=1} 1; END{exit(r)}' >&2; } 3>&1

# grep on stderr, do stop early
{ my_program 2>&1 >&3 | awk -v s="$MSG" '$0~s{exit(1)} 1' >&2; } 3>&1
```

Notes:

- For all: the stream on which you apply `grep` will lose its potential tty status, because `my_program` sees it going into `awk`. This might affect how `my_program` writes to this stream, e.g., it might not print rotating progress bars because it might assume it cannot control cursor position.
- For all: stdout and stderr will not be merged, and can be redirected independently from each other, as usual.
- For all: the original exit code of `my_program` gets completely ignored. The only other easy alternative is: *exit with error if either `my_program` exits with error, or the error message appears*. To get this behaviour, you need to enable `pipefail` in the Bash shell that executes the pipeline. E.g.:

  ```
  (set -o pipefail; my_program | awk -v s="$MSG" '$0~s{exit(1)} 1')
  ```
- For grepping on stderr: the simple command lines above assume file descriptor 3 is unused. That's usually an ok assumption to make. To avoid this assumption, you can get Bash to allocate a file descriptor that's guaranteed to be unused with:

  ```
  bash -c 'exec {fd}>&1; { my_program 2>&1 >&${fd} | awk -v s="$MSG" '\''$0~s{exit(1)} 1'\'' >&2; } ${fd}>&1'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try two terminals side by side.
In the first shell window:

```
tail -F /tmp/xyzzy
```

In the second, just what you were doing, only to the tmp file:

```
my_program | tee /tmp/xyzzy | grep -q "error message"
```

Start them in that order.

It's klunky, as you'll want to clear the temp file every so often, or pick a new name, but it works.

Added later... Try something like:

```
my_program | tee /tmp/xyzzy ; grep -q "error message" /tmp/xyzzy
```

The exit status of the sequence is the exit status of the grep.  Which is inverted from what you want, sigh.  So negate it.

```
my_program | tee /tmp/xyzzy ; ! grep -q "error message" /tmp/xyzzy
```

Comment: Why use 2 terminals?  Maybe I misread the question but I didn't see anything related mentioned.

Comment: To separate the two kinds of output: important stuff being matched by grep, vs. everything.

Comment: I need the output to actually come from the script that's running the program, like it would if the script just ran the program normally.  (It's actually a [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) build script; Jenkins captures the script's output and saves it in a log.  The exit status is so that Jenkins can tell whether the build has failed.)

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Then something like my next answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make a demo function `baz()` that outputs *"foo"* to *stdout* and *"bar"* to *stderr*:

```
baz() { echo foo ; echo bar >& 2 ; }
```

Simple case, run `grep foo` on *stdout*, and `grep bar` on *stderr*:

```
{ baz 2>&1 1>&3 | grep bar 1>&2 ; } 3>&1 | grep foo
```

Same thing, but quietly, using `tee`; the output looks like no `grep`s were used at all:

```
{ baz 2>&1 1>&3 | tee /dev/stderr | grep -q bar ; } 3>&1 | \
{ tee /dev/stderr | grep -q foo ; } 2>&1
```

Now add a conditional after `grep -q bar`, which prints "BEEP!" to *stderr* if *bar* is found:

```
{ baz 2>&1 1>&3 | tee /dev/stderr | grep -q bar && echo "BEEP!" >&2 ; } 3>&1 | \
{ tee /dev/stderr | grep -q foo ; } 2>&1
```

Output of the last two lines:

```
foo
bar
BEEP!
```

Comment: The redirect juggling needs more explanations, to be added later, time permitting...