# quit youtube-dl after n downloads given a batch file is being used

Tags: bash, shell-script

I know that for a single playlist we can use `--playlist-end NUMBER` to quit `youtube-dl` after n downloads.

However, my problem is I am using a batch file.

The `batch-file.txt` looks like

```
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUiueC0kTFqLvpFk_Zg55geh_TBTKnbnA
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL11ZiN8vMsDpdgDscEZZrCfR5vQT_EzvG
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgCYzUzKIBE_ZuZzgts135GuLQNX5eEPk
```

The dry run looks like:

```
$ youtube-dl -i -c --no-warnings --console-title --batch-file='batch-file.txt' -s -o '%(playlist_title)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s'
[youtube:tab] PLUiueC0kTFqLvpFk_Zg55geh_TBTKnbnA: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: Testing Flutter Apps
[youtube:tab] playlist Testing Flutter Apps: Downloading 6 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 6
[youtube] eLMa2jgp_bw: Downloading webpage
[youtube] eLMa2jgp_bw: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 2 of 6
[youtube] nuMqDNUb7f0: Downloading webpage
[youtube] nuMqDNUb7f0: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 3 of 6
[youtube] Vfi0uyDWIuM: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Vfi0uyDWIuM: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 4 of 6
[youtube] 225MFHjQokw: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 225MFHjQokw: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 5 of 6
[youtube] uB5_REsREtU: Downloading webpage
[youtube] uB5_REsREtU: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 6 of 6
[youtube] YjtGT7Cccd0: Downloading webpage
[youtube] YjtGT7Cccd0: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Finished downloading playlist: Testing Flutter Apps
[youtube:tab] PL11ZiN8vMsDpdgDscEZZrCfR5vQT_EzvG: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: Funny Readings
[youtube:tab] playlist Funny Readings: Downloading 7 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 7
[youtube] EShUeudtaFg: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading video 2 of 7
[youtube] 15nNY7uofNw: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading video 3 of 7
[youtube] 4nxsCZ2SEcQ: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading video 4 of 7
[youtube] lhLHXjZyr8I: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading video 5 of 7
[youtube] NmnGt4LBxcQ: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Private video
Sign in if you've been granted access to this video
[download] Downloading video 6 of 7
[youtube] feXHNClEZdI: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading video 7 of 7
[youtube] GH5M4trXnTU: Downloading webpage
[youtube] GH5M4trXnTU: Downloading player b2e56c01
[download] Finished downloading playlist: Funny Readings
[youtube:tab] PLgCYzUzKIBE_ZuZzgts135GuLQNX5eEPk: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: UI Testing for Beginners
[youtube:tab] playlist UI Testing for Beginners: Downloading 20 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 20
[youtube] j8jQq-kYgDU: Downloading webpage
[youtube] j8jQq-kYgDU: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 2 of 20
[youtube] NTBj_0tIlQc: Downloading webpage
[youtube] NTBj_0tIlQc: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 3 of 20
[youtube] zJuFYqnBcgQ: Downloading webpage
[youtube] zJuFYqnBcgQ: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 4 of 20
[youtube] GDTJHaR5yIs: Downloading webpage
[youtube] GDTJHaR5yIs: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 5 of 20
[youtube] ZpFgY6qc_ZY: Downloading webpage
[youtube] ZpFgY6qc_ZY: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 6 of 20
[youtube] KOC_wC3LAoA: Downloading webpage
[youtube] KOC_wC3LAoA: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 7 of 20
[youtube] VuPU6yG0uwg: Downloading webpage
[youtube] VuPU6yG0uwg: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 8 of 20
[youtube] QmH-B_UYIyA: Downloading webpage
[youtube] QmH-B_UYIyA: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 9 of 20
[youtube] CpQQ6-vo5bw: Downloading webpage
[youtube] CpQQ6-vo5bw: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 10 of 20
[youtube] xxO0Z9GzcBU: Downloading webpage
[youtube] xxO0Z9GzcBU: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 11 of 20
[youtube] HRRn6m5hUoA: Downloading webpage
[youtube] HRRn6m5hUoA: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 12 of 20
[youtube] L037q8MGkGA: Downloading webpage
[youtube] L037q8MGkGA: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 13 of 20
[youtube] IaxMgpKwRFY: Downloading webpage
[youtube] IaxMgpKwRFY: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 14 of 20
[youtube] A88735Xv108: Downloading webpage
[youtube] A88735Xv108: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 15 of 20
[youtube] _96FT7E6PL4: Downloading webpage
[youtube] _96FT7E6PL4: Downloading MPD manifest
^[[B[download] Downloading video 16 of 20
[youtube] BPlHmKjQUWo: Downloading webpage
[youtube] BPlHmKjQUWo: Downloading MPD manifest
[download]
```

The first playlist has 6 videos, the second playlist has 7 videos and the third playlist has 20 videos.

I want to quit download after I have downloaded total 18 videos.

I figured out that I have total 33 videos in the three playlist. `Downloading video` appears 33 times in the stdout.

```
$ youtube-dl -i -c --no-warnings -s --console-title -o '%(playlist_title)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s' --batch-file='batch-file.txt' | grep -o "Downloading video" | wc -l
33
```

So, if I quit download when `Downloading video` appears 19th time then it will do the trick.

I [found](https://superuser.com/a/972771) that:

> To kill a process after it gives a specific output, one might use
>
> ```
> mylongrunningtool | stdbuf -o0 egrep '(term1|term2)' >&-
> ```

This code has a problem though. It does not show the stdout.

I think I have to do something like the [following](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463341):

```
var=0
my_program | while read line ; do 
    if echo "$line" | grep "Downloading video" 
    then
        ((i=i+1))
    fi
    if var=20 exit my_program
done
```

Or the [following](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307584) might be helpful as well:

```
my_program | awk 'BEGIN{s=0} /error message/{s=1} 1; END{exit(s)}'
```

But I am not sure how to do it. What can I do?

Comment: In case `max-downloads` doesn't help: To analyze stdout and also display it, consider `tee`.

Comment: @berndbausch how should `mylongrunningtool | stdbuf -o0 egrep '(term1|term2)' >&-
` look like with `tee`?

Comment: @blueray For example `mylongrunningtool | tee myoutput` and in parallel `tail -f myoutput | grep whatever`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments to your question: `youtube-dl` has a specific option for limiting the overall number of downloads:

> `--max-downloads NUMBER`
> Abort after downloading NUMBER files

Using the command and the batch file from your question:

```bsh
youtube-dl -i -c --max-downloads=18 --no-warnings --console-title \
  --batch-file='batch-file.txt' -o '%(playlist_title)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s
```

downloads 6 files from the first playlist, 6 from the second (one fails with  "ERROR: Private video") and 6 from the third. 18 in total.